# Jest / Enzyme wait for the element to have a specific attribute

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, jestjs, enzyme

I'm creating a weather app with React and testing it with enzyme, on each page reload and on the initial page load the background image is supposed to change/load

*App.js*

```
function App() {
  const [background, setBackground] = useState('');


  async function fetchBgImage() {
    // getRandomImage returns a link fetched from the api
    setBackground(await getRandomImage());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBgImage(); //a method which sets the background image and sets background to image url
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      // Here backgound is just an image url
      <img id="background_image" src={background} alt="background image" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the real world the app works fine and the background image load properly and changes on each page reload, but when I'm testing with enzyme, it doesn't wait for the backgound property to be set and, consequently, the src property is empty.

*App.test.js*

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // I read that useEffect doesnt work with shallow rendering 
  // https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2086
  jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation((f) => f());
});

it('displays background image', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  const image = wrapper.find('#background_image');
  // src prop is empty
  console.log(image.props());
});
```

**So how do I make enzyme wait for the src property of the image to be set?**

Comment: It is not clear how do you call fetchBgImage() in your test code, and iy is not clear is fetchBgImage is promise or not... So the problem can be double

Comment: @DmitryReutov Yeah fetchBgImage returns a promise, I edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Then if you want to see changes in your data, triggered by asyncronous code you should use await, or parameter done... Here you can read
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/test-asynchronous-code-jest

Answer (score 0):

You could write a helper function to wait for the attribute. Something like:

```
function waitForAttribute(el, attribute) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const tryInterval = 100; // try every 100ms
        let maxTries = 10; //try 10 times
        let currentTry = 0;

        const timer = setInterval(() => {
          if (currentTry >= maxTries) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return reject(new Error(`${attribute} not found on ${el.debug()}`));
          }

          const prop = el.props()[attribute]

          if (prop) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            resolve(el);
          }
          currentTry++

        }, tryInterval);
  });
}


it('displays background image', async () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  const image = wrapper.find('#background_image');
  const srcValue = await waitForAttribute(image, 'src')
  // ...do something with it
});
```